# Algorithm to find non-zero matrix $N$ such that $N \times M = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given a $p \times q$ matrix $M$, is there an algorithm to find the $q \times p$ matrix $N$ such that:

$$N \times M = 0$$

Assuming $M$ is non-zero, the trivial solution is $N = 0$. I am looking for the non-trivial solution(s) and I appreciate that there will not always be a solution to this problem. In my case the number of columns $q$ of $M$ is larger than the number of rows $p$ of $M$.

Comment: Note that if $M$ is in echelon form, the question is easy. So Gauss's algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) will allow you to construct such an algorithm.

Comment: Look at SVD for homogeneous linear system...

Comment: Are you both implying that the matrix must be singular so a rank revealing decomposition implies how many rows can be arbitrarily chosen and how many rows must be set to zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of the we can rewritten the equality $N\times M=0$ as $\text{}^tM \times \text{}^tN=0$, since $\text{}^t0=0$. So now we resolve the following problem: given the matrix $A$ of size $q\times p$ find a matrix $B$ of dimensions $p\times q$ such that $A\times B=0$.

We can consider the linear homogeneous system associate to matrix $A$ and we call $S$ the space of solution of $A$; I mean a vector $v\in \mathbb{R}^p$ belong to $S$ iff $Av=0$, and we consider different cases:

1- $p\neq q$. Clearly in this case the linear homogeneous system admits non-trivial solution; so $S\neq\{0\}$, in particular $S$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^p$ of dimension $k$, and let $\{v_1,...,v_k\}$ one of its bases. Finally take $B$ the matrix such that every column is a linear combination of $v_1,...,v_k$, then $A\times B=0$ since every column is again a solution of the system above.

2-$p=q$. In this case could be happen that the matrix $A$ is non-singular, in other words $detA\neq0$; then $B$ is necessarily the zero-matrix.
If $A$ is singular, then you can find $B$ in the same way describe above.

Comment: Thanks this is a great explanation. In octave/matlab for matrix $M$

`[U, S, V] = svd(M); b = V(:, size(M, 2));`

gives a basis $b$ if the smallest singular value of $S$ is $0$ or very small.

Comment: You are welcome ;)